# How to convert a matrix whose entries are one digit decimal number from Text file of Latex to console of Scilab in shortcut way?

Tags: pdf, scilab

I have a very big matrix whose entries are one digit decimal number (For example, \begin{bmatrix}
0.3 & 0.2 & 0.1 \ 
0.1 & 0.6 & 0.8 \ 
0.7 & 0.4 & 0.8
\end{bmatrix} ) in a Text file of Latex. My aim is to convert this matrix to Console of Scilab.  Is there any shortcut way to do this?  (The very big matrix means  that it has a maximum of 30 rows and 6 columns).

Comment: Do you have a link to the pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

First put your matrix in file named 'matrix' and remove the `\begin{bmatrix}` and `\end{bmatrix}` entries.

Thus your file 'matrix' should look like:

```
 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.1 \ 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.8 \ 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.8
```

Now execute the following code in scilab:

```
mclose('all')
f=mopen('matrix');

matrix_car='M=[['

while ~(meof(f))
    car = mgetstr(1, f);
    if car == '&' then
        matrix_car=matrix_car+',';
    elseif car == '\' then
            matrix_car=matrix_car+'];[';
    elseif car ~= ascii(10) then
        matrix_car=matrix_car+car;
    end;   
end;

matrix_car=matrix_car+']]'

execstr(matrix_car)
```

Then you will get a variable called `M` with the appropriate matrix in it.